# PowerBI : Dropdown Slicer added to a report changes to List Slicer on reading view or publish

Tags: powerbi

When i add a Slicer set as Dropdown, after saving or publishing on the report in reading view it changes to list slicer. ( this is the option that is present in the header link).

I tried changing the visual size, thought that could be a issue, but does not resolve it.

Also in this visual, the header is turned off.

visual size: 150x70.
Page size: 2048x1080

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem  too

i figure this in my report
i'm using bookmarks!
and update bookmark with the last changes with a list view in the slicer
and after i change to dropdown 
and forget to updatet the bookmark again

you always be back to the list if using the link that use the bookmark

need to update the bookmaek again with the dropdown view and now it's ok !

this was my case 
i hope i help you

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen many times, my only solution so far is to try and refresh, and if all else fails come back in 2-3 hours and/or delete them and remake. This is another doozy of a product from MS have finished.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just had to reset to default:

[image]